# Validity of UK Skilled Worker Visa if employment contract is of one year

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa, indian-citizens

I recently got an offer in an UK Institute for one year and I will need to apply for the Skilled Worker Visa. I am an Indian citizen.

> My question is: How many years of Skilled Worker Visa I will get if the certificate of sponsorship (CoS) indicates that my employment contract is of one year?

I am aware that a maximum 5 year of visa is provided but my understanding is that it also depends on the CoS and length of employment. So I am thinking if anyone can help me to find out what will be the visa duration if the length of employment is one year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visa duration would be one year plus 14 days.

From the “Grant or Refuse” section of the *Skilled Worker caseworker guidance* published by the UK Home Office:

**Dates of permission granted**

For non-EEA nationals, and EEA nationals applying from 1 January 2021, you should grant entry clearance with effect from either the date of decision or a date requested by the applicant, whichever is later.

In both circumstances, the end date of permission must be 14 days after the end date stated on the applicant’s CoS. The end date on their CoS can be up to a maximum of five years after the start date on their CoS.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/974078/skilled-worker-caseworker-guidance-v2.0ext.pdf#page51